# Save XML format to a string instead of a file

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, w3c

I used the DocumentBuilderFactory to create XML file as done here: [How to create XML file with specific structure in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520208/i-would-like-to-create-xml-file-using-java).

Instead of saving it to a file, I want to store the result as a java String. How to achieve that.

Duplicate:
[How do I convert a org.w3c.dom.Document object to a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356258/how-do-i-convert-a-org-w3c-dom-document-object-to-a-string)

Comment: I am using "org.w3c.dom.Document", while there "org.jdom.Document" is used.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356258/how-do-i-convert-a-org-w3c-dom-document-object-to-a-string

Comment: Right. I just found that too. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Can you please mark the question as duplicate. I don't think I can do it myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example may help you out.

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class DOMBasicDoc {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String[] input = {"John Doe,123-456-7890", "Bob Smith,123-555-1212"};
            String[] line = new String[2];
            DocumentBuilderFactory dFact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder build = dFact.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = build.newDocument();
            Element root = doc.createElement("root");
            doc.appendChild(root);
            Element memberList = doc.createElement("members");
            root.appendChild(memberList);
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                line = input[i].split(",");
                Element member = doc.createElement("member");
                memberList.appendChild(member);
                Element name = doc.createElement("name");
                name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(line[0]));
                member.appendChild(name);
                Element phone = doc.createElement("phone");
                phone.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(line[1]));
                member.appendChild(phone);
            }
            TransformerFactory tFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer trans = tFact.newTransformer();

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            trans.transform(source, result);
            System.out.println(writer.toString());

        } catch (TransformerException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error outputting document");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error building document");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to read the Java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) about I/O Streams. Specifically the [characters stream section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html) talking about `Reader` and `Writer` classes.

As you can see [in the `XMLOutputter`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/XMLOutputter.html) JavaDoc the method `output` takes different parameters. You just have to chose the approriate Writer, instead of a `FileWriter` use a `StringWriter` for example.

However, the `XMLOutputter` also have `outputString()` methods that let you produce a String directly doing that job internally (probably).