# XML Document Design

Tags: java, xml

I have a group of working code to construct an XML Request in certain specific format as per below. But the logic was just hardcoded example `emaillist.appendChild` `document.createElement` and so on. Is there any better way of achieving the same result? Maybe using some Stub or Custom XML type Java Entity?

```
public void setXML() throws JAXBException, ParserConfigurationException {

 DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document document = docBuilder.newDocument();
 Element emaillist = document.createElement("EMAILLIST");

 Element templateID = document.createElement("TemplateID");
 templateID.setTextContent("1");

 Element campaignID = document.createElement("CampaignID");
 campaignID.setTextContent("100");

 Element campaignName = document.createElement("CampaignName");
 campaignName.setTextContent("Test Campaign Using XML DS");

 Element category = document.createElement("Category");
 category.setTextContent("Trigger");

 Element email = document.createElement("Email");
 email.setTextContent("test@test.com");

 Element subject = document.createElement("Subject");
 subject.setTextContent("Transactional Submissions");

 Element senderEmail = document.createElement("SenderEmail");
 senderEmail.setTextContent("support@test");

 Element emailBody = document.createElement("EmailBody");
 Element html = document.createElement("html");
 Element head = document.createElement("head");
 Element title = document.createElement("title");
 title.setTextContent("This is test Title : " + ZonedDateTime.now());
 head.appendChild(title);
 Element body = document.createElement("body");
 html.appendChild(head);
 html.appendChild(body);
 emailBody.appendChild(html);

 emaillist.appendChild(templateID);
 emaillist.appendChild(campaignID);
 emaillist.appendChild(campaignName);
 emaillist.appendChild(category);
 emaillist.appendChild(email);
 emaillist.appendChild(subject);
 emaillist.appendChild(senderEmail);
 emaillist.appendChild(emailBody);
 System.out.println(emaillist);

}
```

**Sample Required Output**

```
<EMAILLIST
    xmlns:ns2="TransactionalSubmissionsSvcs"
    xmlns="">
    <TemplateID>1</TemplateID>
    <CampaignID>100</CampaignID>
    <CampaignName>Test Campaign Using XML DS</CampaignName>
    <Category>Trigger</Category>
    <Email>test@test.com.my</Email>
    <Subject>Transactional Submissions</Subject>
    <SenderEmail>test@test.com.my</SenderEmail>
    <EmailBody>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>This is test Title : 2019-03-17T20:32:43.649+08:00</title>
            </head>
            <body/>
        </html>
    </EmailBody>
</EMAILLIST>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520208/how-to-create-xml-file-with-specific-structure-in-java

Comment: The post suggested is as per what i have did. But i’m trying to find a better way to achieve this because i believe my solution now is bad.

Comment: As mentioned in the other questions, you can use JAXB, which will fill you objects automatically with the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `POJO` model which represents your `XML` and after that serialiser it to `XML` using `JAXB`, `Jackson XML` or other library. Example with `POJO` model and `JAXB`:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class JaxbApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(EmailList.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        EmailBody emailBody = new EmailBody();
        emailBody.setTitle("This is test Title : " + ZonedDateTime.now());
        emailBody.setBody("");

        EmailList emailList = new EmailList();
        emailList.setTemplateId(1);
        emailList.setCampaignId(100);
        emailList.setCampaignName("Test Campaign Using XML DS");
        emailList.setCategory("Trigger");
        emailList.setEmail("test@test.com.my");
        emailList.setSubject("Transactional Submissions");
        emailList.setSenderEmail("test@test.com.my");
        emailList.setEmailBody(emailBody);

        marshaller.marshal(emailList, System.out);
    }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "EMAILLIST", namespace = "TransactionalSubmissionsSvcs")
class EmailList {

    @XmlElement(name = "TemplateID")
    private int templateId;

    @XmlElement(name = "CampaignID")
    private int campaignId;

    @XmlElement(name = "CampaignName")
    private String campaignName;

    @XmlElement(name = "Category")
    private String category;

    @XmlElement(name = "Email")
    private String email;

    @XmlElement(name = "Subject")
    private String subject;

    @XmlElement(name = "SenderEmail")
    private String senderEmail;

    @XmlElement(name = "EmailBody")
    private EmailBody emailBody;

    // getters, setters
}

class EmailBody {

    private String title;
    private String body;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Above code prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:EMAILLIST xmlns:ns2="TransactionalSubmissionsSvcs">
    <TemplateID>1</TemplateID>
    <CampaignID>100</CampaignID>
    <CampaignName>Test Campaign Using XML DS</CampaignName>
    <Category>Trigger</Category>
    <Email>test@test.com.my</Email>
    <Subject>Transactional Submissions</Subject>
    <SenderEmail>test@test.com.my</SenderEmail>
    <EmailBody>
        <body></body>
        <title>This is test Title : 2019-03-18T00:03:48.168+01:00</title>
    </EmailBody>
</ns2:EMAILLIST>
```

If you really need `html` and `head` elements you need to create simple `POJO` wrappers.